# Unable to build project with Google APIs (.Net)

Tags: .net, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm unable to build a project that uses the Google APIs.  I followed the build instructions at https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/Build.  I get several errors like the following:

```
Warning 5   The primary reference "Google.Apis" could not be resolved because
it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Net.Http, Version=1.5.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the
currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "Google.Apis" or retarget your application to a framework 
version which contains "System.Net.Http, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
```

I also tried using NuGet to resolve dependencies, but I get:

```
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Zlib.Portable 1.9.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targe
ts '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework. 
For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:16
+ install-package <<<<  google.apis -pre
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

The documentation says the the 4.0 Full Profile is supported.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431975/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-net-http-version-2-0-0-0-in-mvc4-web-ap http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16756186/system-net-http-could-not-be-resolved-in-the-currently-targeted-framework-net-4

Comment: Let me know what solution works for you, because there are several users who complain about a similar problem. Thanks!

Comment: @peleyal As I look back at it, I think it failed because I had a file in my project called service.vb.

Answer (score 1):

I've got it working now.  I'm not exactly sure what fixed it.

I had an old version of NuGet installed in VS 2010. I might have originally installed it as an administrator, because I had to open VS2010 as an administrator to remove it.  After removing NuGet, I installed the latest version.  I was then able to do `package-install google.apis -pre` and `package-install google.apis.authentication -pre` with success.  But my project still wouldn't compile. From my memory, though I could be wrong, the only other thing that I did was remove the Google API Lib references from a separate project in the same solution, and then the compile errors were gone.

Answer (score 0):

you need install
[latest NuGet](http://nuget.codeplex.com/), it helped to me

Comment: I had the latest NuGet installed, maybe they fixed a problem.